# Getting error "The type or namespace name 'SelectList' could not be found" even though I have MVC installed, and have the using statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Git cloned an old project from work into VS 2015. When building the project, I get the error

> "The type or namespace name 'SelectList' could not be found"

I have opened the nuget package manager and made sure asp.net mvc is installed and good to go. I also have the statement `using System.Web.Mvc;` at the top in the using statements.

I updated mvc through the package manager to see if that would help, but I am still getting the error.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using .....;
using .....;

namespace WorkPermit.Logic
{
    public class RoleService : IDisposable
    {
        public SelectList GetRolesList()
        {
            var roles = _roleManager.Roles.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.Name,
                Value = m.Name,
            }).ToList();
            return new SelectList(roles, "Value", "Text");
        }
    }
}
```

Since I have mvc installed and the using statement, I am curious why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Navigate to the References directory of your project and delete and re-add the `System.Web.Mvc` reference.